# How to safely display html emails?

Tags: email, xss, html

I'm building a webmail application using php at the moment. I'm getting the email content from gmail using Imap and wanted to display the email as close as I can to how gmail shows it. Is it safe to display the raw html body from the email or is there additional steps I should take to ensure my application is secure from attacks?

I also looked at this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82766/how-to-safely-display-html-emails-like-gmail-does-it) "how-to-safely-display-html-emails-like-gmail-does-it" but its from 5 years ago and couldn't find any recent sources on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to sanitize the content before embedding it in your HTML output, otherwise you are guaranteed to have XSS vulnerabilities in there.

Please do not reinvent the wheel, as there are great sanitizers out there, that you can utilize. I highly recommend using [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify), which is also integrated in several widely used JS frameworks to reliably protect against XSS. It aims at being secure by default, but also offers capability for configuration and fine tuning.

Comment: Perfect, if you need it for java like me, there's also an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413297/how-to-sanitize-html-code-in-java-to-prevent-xss-attacks